# Question about the E-step in the EM algorithm

Tags: expectation-maximization

In the EM algorithm, the E-step is

$\int l(\theta|X_{obs},X_{mis})f(X_{mis}|X_{obs},\theta)dX_{mis}$

, which means it tries to derive the expectation of $l(\theta|X_{obs},X_{mis})$ by the distribution of $f(X_{mis}|X_{obs},\theta)$. However, in page 2 of [this article](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~yuille/courses/stat153/emtutorial.pdf)(I thinks this is also derived by the same way in Little and Rubin 2002), it is derived that the E-step is as $E_{\theta^{0}}[l(\theta|X)|X_{obs}]$, and I do have problem to figure out why $\int l(\theta|X_{obs},X_{mis})f(X_{mis}|X_{obs},\theta)dX_{mis}$ can be represented as $E_{\theta^{0}}[l(\theta|X)|X_{obs}]$. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: The EM algorithm was introduced by Dempster, Laird and Rubin in a famous paper in the Journal of the Royal Statistical Society in 1977. It provides a way to obtain maximum likelihood estimation with incomplete (missing) data. They illustrated broad applications (in addition to missing value problems it includes problems with grouped, censored  and truncated data and finite mixture models and more. The article you reference provides a good summary.

Comment: Because of the many applications I think it may be that Little and Rubin may use different notation than your reference article. I will look into it and see later if I can answer your question.